# How to adjust a specular map's strength?

Tags: node-editor

When connecting a specular map to the Principled BSDF's specular node, I can't set the specular value anymore.
How do I set the specular map's strength?

[image]

Comment: you can use a Converter > ColorRamp, or a Converter > Math (Multiply mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly set the value - it is generated by the connected *.PNG file.

However, you can make the effect stronger or weaker.
Add *math node* in front of it and set it to *multiply*.
This works for most situations.

Just like this:
[image: using math node to multiply values]

Important Note:
*Avoid* connecting textures into specular input, if you’re going for physically accurate result.
Use metalness texture instead and connect it to metalness input. And keep the default specular value of 0,5.
(CG Cookie explained it best: https://youtu.be/mrNMpqdNchY?t=244)

If something ain’t clear, let me know. Specular input is kinda weird, I don’t want to overwhelm you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: @janewang Happy to help.
If this solved your problem, you can mark the answer as accepted.
(Click the checkmark).